# Forestry Service Raster ImageServer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-image-server

I routinely use these Raster Services (http://forestrymaps.alaska.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Rasters) for reference in GoogleEarth, but I'd much rather have access to them in QGIS. I've tried various combinations/that have worked for other services I stream, however this one has me stumped. I tried installing the ArcGIS REST API Connector, however it keeps giving me an error. I've reviewed various posts on this forum and haven't found a solution yet. I am running the stable build 2.14.16-Essen

Combinations I've tried:

Using Layer URLs In ArcGIS REST API Connector:

- http://forestrymaps.alaska.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Rasters/AK_63360_Topo/ImageServer/exportImage? (This is the address that my Google Earth Network Link is able to use)
- http://forestrymaps.alaska.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Rasters/AK_63360_Topo/ImageServer
- Various vector WMS layers from the same site (I get syntax errors when I try to connect these)

Using Other tools:

- Standard WM(T)S Add layer tool. (Tried more address links than I can count...)
- WCS Add Layer. This at least tries to connect, but I get error windows that vary depending on the address link tried

My understanding of how these services function is mostly gained by trial & error. This is one I really want to use, and I know I can access it through Google Earth, so I must be only limited by my own ignorance.

Comment: Perhaps this thread may be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202615/adding-arcgis-online-services-to-qgis (possible duplicate)

Comment: Thank you, @buddiebubba 's answer was what originally pointed me to the ArcGIS REST API Connector plugin, however I keep getting syntax errors. I don't know if it's because I'm trying to connect to an ImageServer, or if it's because there's no WMS service, or another problem. All of the help posts I've found so far are dealing with vector data, though I'm not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I've been able to determine if the REST API url ends in `MapServer` you're in luck and you can use the native Qgis Add-Layer menu. However if the url ends in `ImageServer` you need to use this plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ImageServerConnector/

There is a bright light at the end of the tunnel since this part of the API and thus scriptable, but it means that at this point you can only get there through scripting.

[Configure which bands to display from a 4-band ArcGIS image service?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231889/in-qgis-how-do-i-configure-which-bands-to-display-from-a-4-band-arcgis-image-se) has an example of how construct a url to fetch data from `ImageServer`service. A long way from a script, but a signpost along the way.

Comment: Holding out hope for a non-scripting solution since I'm a python baby, but I'll come back & vote this up if I learn to fix it before that happens. :)

Comment: Note to anonymous editor: thanks very much for changing "there is no ready tool" to an active plugin link. It is best practice to also add a comment below or inline that the post has been updated from the original.